# How to exclude fields from the response when deserializing Elasticsearch query results in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, jackson-databind

I am using Spring Boot 2.6.14 and I have an entity class MyEntity that represents documents in an Elasticsearch index. I want to execute a search query on the index and deserialize the results into instances of MyEntity. However, I only want to include certain fields in the response, based on the includes and excludes options in the _source field of the query.

Here is my MyEntity class::

```
@Document(indexname = "index_name")
@JsonInclude
public class MyEntity {

  @JsonSetter("_id")
  private Long id; 

  @JsonSetter("field_1")
  private String fieldOne;

  @JsonSetter("field_2")
  private String fieldTwo;

  @JsonSetter("field_3")
  private String fieldThree; //I want to hide this to the user and only return fields that are in the includes.
}
```

Here is an example of a search query that I want to execute::

```
POST index_name/_search
{
    "_source": {
        "includes": [ "_id", "field_1", "field_2" ],
        "excludes": [ "field_3" ]
    },
    "query": {
        "match" : { "field_1" : "value1" }
    }
}
```

or

```
POST index_name/_search
{
    "_source": {
        "includes": [ "_id", "field_1", "field_3" ],
        "excludes": [ "field_2" ]
    },
    "query": {
        "match" : { "field_1" : "value1" }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of a document in the index::

```
{
  "_index": "index_name",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "1",
  "_source": {
    "field_1": "value1",
    "field_2": null,
    "field_3": "value3"
  }
}
```

When I execute the search query and deserialize the results into instances of MyEntity, I expect to get a response like this::

```
{
    "id": 1
    "fieldOne": "value1",
    "fieldTwo": null
}
```

for the second query, the expected response::

```
{
    "id": 1
    "fieldOne": "value1",
    "fieldThree": "value3"
}
```

However, what I actually get the first query is this::

```
{
    "id": 1
    "fieldOne": "value1",
    "fieldThree": null
}
```

and second, I get:

```
{
    "id": 1
    "fieldOne": "value1",
    "fieldTwo": null,
    "fieldThree": "value3"
}
```

How can I exclude the fieldThree field from the response when deserializing the Elasticsearch query results?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization#filters

Answer (score 0):

Add `@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)` to the field you want to be extracted from the response but not included on serialization.

Comment: The fields that are extracted are dynamic and can be included or excluded based on the user’s selection.

Comment: Oh, didn't get it. Well, then any static approach won't work, you need custom serializer.

Comment: Yes, I have used a custom serializer/deserializer.